# how to use radio group inside a list item in a listview without changing its state?

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, baseadapter, radio-group

I am trying to use a radio group of 4 radio buttons inside a list item of a list view. When i scroll the list the radio button are changing their state. I have looked for this but i dint understand how to modify my code. Im a new to android.

My custom adapter code:

```
    public class AttendanceInputListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TodaysClasses>  {

    Context context;
    static ArrayList<Integer> action;
    public static ArrayList<TodaysClasses> daySubjects;

    public AttendanceInputListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<TodaysClasses> allTodaysClasses) {
        super(context,0,allTodaysClasses);
        daySubjects = allTodaysClasses;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.day_classes_listitem,parent,false);
        }

        action = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < daySubjects.size(); i++) {
            action.add(0);
        }

        TodaysClasses currentItem = getItem(position);

        TextView SubjectName = (TextView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.SubjectNameAttendanceInput);
        assert currentItem != null;
        SubjectName.setText(currentItem.getSubjectName());

        RadioButton attended = (RadioButton)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.Attended);
        attended.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                    action.set(position,1);
            }
        });

        RadioButton absent = (RadioButton)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.absent);
        absent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                    action.set(position,2);
            }
        });

        RadioButton cancled = (RadioButton)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.classCanceled);
        cancled.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
                if (b)
                    action.set(position,3);
            }
        });

        Button changeSubject = (Button)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.changeSubjectButton);
        changeSubject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                FragmentManager manager = ((Activity)context).getFragmentManager();
                ChandSubjectDialog pop = new ChandSubjectDialog();
                pop.show(manager, "No Of classes a day");

            }
        });

        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

Please help me...
Thank You.

Comment: @Uknight plz do help when ur free...

Comment: @AnjaliTripathi

Comment: LisrView with radioGroup is such an idiot idea

Answer (score 0):

Just use radioGroup with radioButton,.
Don't use LisrView with radioGroup with radioButton.